# BBEdit asks for Apple ID password on every launch

Tags: applications, apple-id, mac-appstore

When BBEdit came out on the App Store, I removed the app bundle that I downloaded from the website, and installed via Mac App Store. Now every time I launch the app, it asks for my Apple ID password.

Is there a way to fix it, or should I just go back to using the version that I downloaded from the website?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Try this: 1. Uninstall the App Store version. 2. Install the website version. 3. Install [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) 4. Uninstall the website version using AppCleaner. 4. Restart. 5. Install the App Store version. Now check if are able to get rid of the issue.

Comment: Please [contact BareBones](http://www.barebones.com/contact/), the developers of BBEdit. They are best placed to help you fix this problem. By talking to them directly you will help BareBones learn what problems are affecting their customers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a customer support question for BBEdit's developer, BareBones.

Comment: Reply from OP: "Using AppCleaner helped! Removed it completely and reinstalled from the App Store, the problem seems to be gone. Thank you all for your replies."

Comment: @NimeshNeema Reopened, please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following steps to resolve the issue:

1. Uninstall the Mac App Store version. (Start Launchpad, press and hold <kbd>Option</kbd> key, and click on the **⨂** button shown at the top left of the BBEdit app icon.)
2. Download and re-install BBEdit from official website.
3. Install [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) app.
4. Uninstall the version of BBEdit installed in step #2 using AppCleaner.
5. Restart your Mac.
6. Now, reinstall BBEdit from the Mac App Store.

Now you should be able to get rid of the issue.